# Declare Consumer and action with it in one line

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, consumer

Experimenting with my code I was wondering is there any way to "compress" it more (one-liner is an ultimate goal).

*vanilla java:*

```
public void setUsingSwitch(Field field, String value) {
    switch (field) {
        case FIRST_NAME:
            setFirstName(value);
            break;
        case LAST_NAME:
            setLastName(value);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Unknow field " + field);
    }
}
```

*"compressed":*

```
public void setUsingConsumer(Field field, String value) {
    Consumer<String> setter = field == FIRST_NAME ? this::setFirstName : field == LAST_NAME ? this::setLastName : v -> {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Unknow field " + field);
    };
    setter.accept(value);
}
```

For both used:

```
public static enum Field { FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME }

void setFirstName(String value) { }

void setLastName(String value) { }
```

Of course it is just scientific interest for me but is there any way to write even smaller code?

Comment: Any reason not to make your `Field` enum have an abstract `setValue` method, which you override in each case?

Comment: You could let the enum values do the job. Give them a method that does it.

Comment: Frankly, I find the first one much more readable than the second one. And adding a middle name will even increase the readability gap.

Comment: @JonSkeet I know it's a bad idea but in my real life code there is a String variable instead of enum just because of business logic. Either sometimes we have to separate logic and having such methods inside enums like Field  can be not recommended in some cases.

Comment: Aha! If this String field would be "FirstName" etc. you might even do `this.getMethod("set"+ field, String.class).invoke(this, value)`. - Java is not for golfing.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree with you about readability. I'm just wondering:  1 - can I throw exception without curly braces? 2 - Can I declare consumer and use it's *accept* method in one line?

Comment: You can write the whole class on one line if you want. But what's the point?

Comment: If your real problem doesn't involve an enum, it would really help if your question didn't either...

Comment: @JonSkeet If solution with *enum* usage is rather good than let it be - it always possible to create another *enum* as wrapper in any class (with own business logic).

Comment: Right - in which case, that goes back to my first comment. Basically, either you *do* want a solution to the question you actually asked, in which case I don't know why you effectively rejected my first comment... or you don't, in which case you shouldn't have included an enum in your question.

Comment: @JonSkeet First of all sorry for your *effectively rejected* comment - I really did not think to anyhow reject it. Even more - I think it could be in answers part. As I said previously *enum* is not a problem for me at all - it can be easily created. Direct answer - both parts (especially with critic) are interesting to me.

Comment: Well, Tagir's answer is basically the one I would have given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach which is not shorter, but sometimes preferable:

```
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

public class MyObj {
    public static enum Field {
        FIRST_NAME(MyObj::setFirstName),
        LAST_NAME(MyObj::setLastName);

        Field(BiConsumer<MyObj, String> setter) {
            this.setter = setter;
        }

        final BiConsumer<MyObj, String> setter;
    }

    public void set(Field field, String value) {
        field.setter.accept(this, value);
    }

    public void setFirstName(String s) {...}
    public void setLastName(String s) {...}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you revealed that you actually don’t have an `enum`, a more general solution may look like this:

```
class Person {
    public void setFirstName(String value) {
        // …
    }
    public void setLastName(String value) {
        // …
    }
    static final Map<String,BiConsumer<Person,String>> FIELDS;
    static {
        Map<String,BiConsumer<Person,String>> m=new HashMap<>();
        m.put("FirstName", Person::setFirstName);
        m.put("LastName", Person::setLastName);
        FIELDS=Collections.unmodifiableMap(m);
    }
    public void setField(String field, String value) {
        FIELDS.getOrDefault(field, (k,v)->{ throw new NoSuchElementException(); })
              .accept(this, value);
    }
}
```

By the way, since you said “business logic”, I recommend the following read: “[Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)”

Answer (score 1):

Given your initial design, I guess you want to enum all possible setters for a *Person*. Further it seams as if you want to collect the *Field* to set and the *value* and afterwards call the proper setter. This is my solution preserving your design goals:

```
public enum Field {

    FIRST_NAME {
        public void setValue(String value, Person person) {
            person.setFirstName(value);
        }},

    LAST_NAME {
        public void setValue(String value, Person person) {
            person.setLastName(value);
        }};

    public abstract void setValue(String value, Person person);
}

public class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void clearUsingConsumer(Field field, String value) {
        field.setValue(value, this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came to the end with [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html):

```
Field field = FIRST_NAME;

Optional.<Consumer<String>>ofNullable(
        field == FIRST_NAME
                ? this::setFirstName
                : field == LAST_NAME
                        ? this::setLastName
                        : null).orElseThrow(IndexOutOfBoundsException::new)
        .accept("John");
```

Although I'm not sure that writing it in one line is a good thing. Or even using it instead of simple `switch`.